# Maximum binary number a binary string will result to if only one operation is allowed i.e. Right-Rotate By K-Bits where K = [0, Length of String]

Tags: c, algorithm, bit-manipulation

Suppose you have a binary string `S` and you are only allowed to do one operation i.e. `Right-Rotate by K-bits` where `K = [0, Length of the string]`. Write an algorithm that will print the maximum binary-number you can create by the defined process.

For Example:

1. `S = [00101]` then maximum value I can get from the process is `10100` i.e. `20`.
2. `S = [011010]` then maximum value I can get from the process is `110100` i.e. `52`.
3. `S = [1100]` then maximum value I can get from the process is `1100` i.e. `12`.

The length of the string `S` has an upper-limit i.e. `5*(10^5)`.

The idea which I thought of is kind of very naive which is: as we know that when you right-rotate any binary number by `1-bit`, you get the same binary number after `m` rotations where `m = number of bits required to represent that number`.
So, I right-rotate by `1` until I get to the number with which I started with and during the process, I keep track of the max-value I encountered and in last I print the max-value.

Is there an efficient approach to solve the problem?

**UPD1:** This the source of the problem [**One-Zero**](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/mnnit-opc-2k20-2-0/challenges/one-zero-2/problem), it all boils down to the statement I have described above.

**UPD2:** As the answer can be huge, the program will print the answer modulo `10^9 + 7.`

Comment: Off the top of my head, I would build a list of string locations (equivalent to rotations) that start with `one`, if any exist. Then, among these look for those that continue with `one`, if any exist. Then among those look for those that continue with `one`, if any exist, and so on. If no `one` continuation exist you just proceed with the `zero` continuation and increment the offset from the start position. This continues until just one string is left. Does this make sense?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError There is something in the back of my head which says that I need to look for consecutive ones in the given binary string but I am not able to claim that it will always give the required answer, however, can you explain your approach through a program in `C, C++ or Python`

Comment: I probably could but not right now.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Ok :)

Comment: Are you really supposed to write the largest decimal number? If the string is long (maximum length being 500000 bits), the largest number can far exceed arithmetic types available in C

Comment: @chqrlieforyellowblockquotes Ya but according to the problem statement, I need to print the answer modulo `10^9 + 7.`

Comment: In passing, I note that if the answer required is the _largest (value modulo 10^9 + 7)_, rather than the _(largest value)  modulo 10^9 + 7_, then the answer can be found in two passes across the string and approximately one `%` operation per character per pass.

Comment: @ChrisHall Can you elaborate on this idea, please?

Comment: If we say the string with zero rotation has value _V0_, then we start by calculating the modulus _M0 = V0 % (10^9 + 7)_.  Also calculate _MSB = 2^(N-1) %  (10^9 + 7)_ -- for _N_ digit string.  Now if _V1_ is _V0_ rotated right by _1_ then if _V0 < 2^(N-1)_ we have _V1 = V0 * 2_ otherwise we have _V1 = (V - 2^(N-1)) * 2 + 1_.  So we can calculate _M1 = V1 % (10^9 + 7)_  using _V0, M0_ and _MSB_.  And we can calculate _Mn_ from _Mn-1_ and _Vn-1_.

Comment: @ChrisHall Can you explain it with an example?

Comment: So if we say that _MSV0_ is the ms-bit of _V0_, and _X = 10^9 + 7_ we can: `if (MSV0 == 0) { M1 = M0 * 2 ; } else { M1 = M0 ; if (M1 < MSB)  M1 += X ; M1 = M1 * 2 + 1 ; } ; M1 = M1 % X ;`

Comment: Sorry, typo: for `M1 = M1 * 2 + 1 ;` read `M1 = (M1 - MSB) * 2 + 1 ;`.  I suggest trying this for all 7 character strings, with _X=19_ to see how it works.  But the basis of this is the same as the mechanism for calculating the modulus across the long string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to find the largest number expressed in a binary encoded string with wrap around.

Here are steps for a solution:

1. let `len` be the length of the string
2. allocate an array of size `2 * len` and duplicate the string to it.
3. using linear search, find the position `pos` of the largest substring of length `len` in this array (lexicographical order can be used for that).
4. compute `res`, the converted number modulo 10<sup>9</sup>+7, reading `len` bits starting at `pos`.
5. free the array and return `res`.

Here is a simple implementation as a function:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

long max_bin(const char *S) {
    size_t i, pos, len;
    char *a;
    // long has at least 31 value bits, enough for numbers upto 2 * 1000000007
    long res;

    if ((len = strlen(S)) == 0)
        return 0;

    if ((a = malloc(len + len)) == NULL)
        return -1;

    memcpy(a, S, len);
    memcpy(a + len, S, len);
    // find the smallest right rotation for the greatest substring
    for (pos = i = len; --i > 0;) {
        if (memcmp(a + i, a + pos, len) > 0)
            pos = i;
    }
    res = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        res = res + res + a[pos + i] - '0';
        if (res >= 1000000007)
            res -= 1000000007;
    }
    free(a);
    return res;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        printf("[%s] -> %ld\n", argv[i], max_bin(argv[i]));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It is feasible to avoid memory allocation if it is a requirement.

Comment: Can you explain with an example like say `N = 011010`?  I am getting `a = 0, b = 0, c = 2` and after the condition `c < a + b, c will be 2` but how do you arrive at the answer which should be `52` in this case. Moreover, does the answer is based on observation or there is a mathematical proof behind it?

Comment: @strikersps: sorry, I misread the problem statement. I have another solution I will submit soon.

Comment: @strikersps: I just posted a new solution with a simple and effective algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for the elegant solution. Moreover, can you tell me why you are making two copies of the given string into a string length `2 * len`. I am interested in the thought process behind it and would there be a performance drop if I use `strncmp()` instead of `memcmp()`? The time complexity of the algorithm is quadratic, can I optimise it further?

Comment: @strikersps: I am making 2 copies of the string to simplify the comparison. It is possible to work directly on the original string but the comparison is more cumbersome and may require 2 calls to `memcmp()`. `strncmp()` would be slower than `memcmp()` because of the needless tests for null terminators.

Comment: @strikersps:  The time complexity is indeed quadratic in pathological cases with repeating patterns, especially for all `0`s and all `1`s. You could avoid some pathological cases by searching for the longest sequences of `1`s and only compare the strings at those offsets, but a string with a repeated pattern `10` would still require quadratic time.

Comment: Thanks! I think we can make the above solution much faster by taking care of repetitions like in case of `10101010`, don't you think?

Comment: @strikersps: repetitive patterns of any kind are pathological cases for this algorithm. Do you have a way to handle them generically?

Comment: I am not sure, but what if we store the repetitive pattern like in case of `101010`, we store `10` in a string, and as we know right-rotate by that many bits will give me same string again means in `101010` if right-rotate by 2, I get the same string `101010`. As in your algorithm, whenever `i` is decremented it generates the next right-rotated string, why not we check whether the new right-rotated string is equal to the pattern or not if it is then `break` there because the answer is not going to get affected I guess. Again its a guess without any mathematical argument.

Comment: @strikersps: the problem is we don't know in advance what patterns to look for, and it is more costly to try and detect them than to just run the brute force scan.

Answer (score 1):

It's me again.

I got to thinking a bit more about your problem in the shower this morning, and it occurred to me that you could do a QuickSelect (if you're familiar with that) over an array of the start indexes of the input string and determine the index of the most "valuable" rotate based on that.

What I show here does not concern itself with presenting the result the way you are required to, only with determining what the best offset for rotation is.

This is not a textbook QuickSelect implementation but rather a simplified method that does the same thing while taking into account that it's a string of zeros and ones that we are dealing with.

Main driver logic:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(FindBestIndex(""));                     // exp -1
    Console.WriteLine(FindBestIndex("1"));                    // exp 0
    Console.WriteLine(FindBestIndex("0"));                    // exp 0
    Console.WriteLine(FindBestIndex("110100"));               // exp 0
    Console.WriteLine(FindBestIndex("100110"));               // exp 3
    Console.WriteLine(FindBestIndex("01101110"));             // exp 4
    Console.WriteLine(FindBestIndex("11001110011"));          // exp 9
    Console.WriteLine(FindBestIndex("1110100111110000011"));  // exp 17
}
```

Set up the index array that we'll be sorting, then call `FindHighest` to do the actual work:

```
static int FindBestIndex(string input)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
        return -1;

    int[] indexes = new int[input.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < indexes.Length; i++)
    {
        indexes[i] = i;
    }

    return FindHighest(input, indexes, 0, input.Length);
}
```

Partition the index array into two halves depending on whether each index points to a string that starts with zero or one at this offset within the string.

Once that's done, if we have just one element that started with one, we have the best string, else if we have more, partition those based on the next index. If none started with one, proceed with zero in the same way.

```
static int FindHighest(string s, int[] p, int index, int len)
{
    // allocate two new arrays, 
    // one for the elements of p that have zero at this index, and
    // one for the elements of p that have one at this index
    int[] zero = new int[len];
    int[] one = new int[len];
    int count_zero = 0;
    int count_one = 0;

    // run through p and distribute its elements to 'zero' and 'one'
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        int ix = p[i]; // index into string
        int pos = (ix + index) % s.Length; // wrap for string length

        if (s[pos] == '0')
        {
            zero[count_zero++] = ix;
        }
        else
        {
            one[count_one++] = ix;
        }
    }

    // if we have a one in this position, use that, else proceed with zero (below)
    if (count_one > 1)
    {
        // if we have more than one, sort on the next position (index)
        return FindHighest(s, one, index + 1, count_one);
    } else if (count_one == 1)
    {
        // we have exactly one entry left in ones, so that's the best one we have overall
        return one[0];
    }

    if (count_zero > 1)
    {
        // if we have more than one, sort on the next position (index)
        return FindHighest(s, zero, index + 1, count_zero);
    }
    else if (count_zero == 1)
    {
        // we have exactly one entry left in zeroes, and we didn't have any in ones, 
        // so this is the best one we have overall
        return zero[0];
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Note that this can be optimized further by expanding the logic: If the input string has any `one`s at all, there's no point in adding indexes where the string starts with `zero` to the index array in `FindBestIndex` since those will be inferior. Also, if an index does start with a `one` but the previous index also did, you can omit the current one as well because the previous index will always be better since that string flows into this character.

If you like, you can also refactor to remove the recursion in favor of a loop.

Answer (score 1):

If I were tackling this I would do so as follows.

I think it's all to do with counting alternating runs of '1' and runs of '0', treating a run of '1's followed by a run of '0's as a pair, then bashing a list of those pairs.

Let us start by scanning to the first '1', and setting start position *s*.  Then count each run of '1's *c1* and the following run of '0's *c0*, creating pairs *(c1,c0)*.

The scan then proceeds forwards to the end, wrapping round as required.  If we represent runs of one or more '1' and '0' as single digits, and '|' as the start and end of the string, then we have cases:

```
    |10101010|
     ^ initial start position s   -- the string ends neatly with a run of '0's

    |1010101|
       ^ new start position s     -- the string starts and ends in a '1', so the first 
                                     run of '1's and run of '0's are rotated (left),
                                     to be appended to the last run of '1's

                                     Note that this changes our start position.

    |01010101|
      ^ initial start position s  -- the first run of '0's is rotated (left), 
                                     to follow the last run of '1's.
    |010101010|
      ^ initial start position s  -- the first run of '0's is rotated (left), 
                                     to be appended to the last run of '0's.
```

NB: if the string both starts and ends with a '1', there are, initially, *n* runs of '0's and *n+1* runs of '1's, but the rotation reduces that to *n* runs of '1's.  And similarly, but conversely, if the string both starts and ends with a '0'.

Let us use *A* as shorthand for the pair *(a1,a0)*.  Suppose we have another pair, *X* -- *(x1,x0)* -- then can compare the two pairs, thus:

- if *a1 > x1* or (*a1 = x1* and (*a0 < x0*) => *A > X*  -- *A* is better start
- if *a1 = x1* and *a0 = x0*                 => *A = X*
- if *a1 < x1* or (*a1 = x1* and (*a0 > x0*) => *A < X*  -- *X* is better start

The trick is probably to pack each pair into an integer -- say *(x1 * N) - x0*, where *N* is at least the maximum allowed length of the string -- for ease of comparison.

During the scan of the string (described above) let us construct a vector of pairs.  During that process, collect the largest pair value *A*, and a list of the positions, *s*, of each appearance of *A*.  Each *s* on the list is a potential best start position.  (The recorded *s* needs to be the index in the vector of pairs and the offset in the original string.)

[If the input string is truly vast, then constructing the entire vector of all pairs will eat memory.  In which case the vector would need to be handled as a "virtual" vector, and when an item in that vector is required, it would have to be created by reading the respective portion of the actual string.]

Now:

1. let us simplify groups of two or more contiguous *A*.  Clearly the second and subsequent *A*'s in such a group cannot be the best start, since there is a better one immediately to the left.  So, in the scan we need to record only the *s* for the first *A* of such groups.
2. if the string starts with one or more *A*'s and ends with one or more *A*'s, need to "rotate" to collect those as a single group, and record the *s* only for the leftmost *A* in that group (in the usual way).

If there is only one *s* on the list, our work is done.  If the string is end-to-end *A*, that will be spotted here.

Otherwise, we need to consider the pairs which follow each of the *s* for our (initial) *A*'s -- where when we say 'follow' we include wrapping round from the end to the start of the string (and, equivalently, the list of pairs).

NB: at this point we know that all the (initial) *A*'s on our list are followed by zero or more *A*'s and then at least one *x*, where *x < A*.

So, set *i = 1*, and consider all the pairs at *s+i* for our list of *s*.  Keep only the *s* for the instances of the largest pair found.  So for *i = 1*, in this example we are considering pairs *x, y* and *z*:

- *...Ax....Az...Az..Ax...Ay...*

And if *x* is the largest, this pass discards *Ay* and both *Az*.  If only one *s* remains -- in the example, *y* is the largest -- our work is done.  Otherwise, repeat for *i = i+1*.

There is one last (I think) wrinkle.  Suppose after finding *z* to be the largest of the *ith* pairs, we have:

- *...A===zA===z...*

where the two runs *===* are the same as each other.  By the same logic that told us to ignore second and subsequent *A*'s in runs of same, we can now discard the second *A===z*.  Indeed we can discard third, fourth, etc. contiguous *A===z*.  Happily that deals with the extreme case of (say):

- *=zA===zA===zA==*

where the string is a sequence of *A===z* !

---

I dunno, that all seems more complicated than I expected when I set out with my pencil and paper :-(

I imagine someone much cleverer than I can reduce this to some standard greatest prefix-string problem.

---

I was bored today, so I knocked out some code (and revised it on 10-Apr-2020).

```
typedef unsigned int uint ;    // assume that's uint32_t or similar

enum { max_string_len = 5 * 100000 } ;  // 5 * 10^5

typedef uint64_t pair_t ;

static uint
one_zero(const char* str, uint N)
{
  enum { debug = false } ;

  void*     mem ;
  size_t    nmx ;

  uint  s1, s0 ;        // initial run of '1'/'0's to be rotated
  uint  s ;

  pair_t*   pv ;        // pair vector
  uint*     psi ;       // pair string index
  uint*     spv ;       // starts vector -- pair indexes

  uint  pn ;            // count of pairs
  uint  sn ;            // count of starts
  pair_t    bp ;        // current best start pair value
  uint  bpi ;           // current best start pair index
  uint  bsc ;           // count of further best starts

  char  ch ;

  if (N > max_string_len)
    {
      printf("*** N = %u > max_string_len (%u)\n", N, max_string_len) ;
      return UINT_MAX ;
    } ;

  if (N < 1)
    {
      printf("*** N = 0 !!\n") ;
      return UINT_MAX ;
    } ;

  // Decide on initial start position.

  s = s1 = s0 = 0 ;
  if (str[0] == '0')
    {
      // Start at first '1' after initial run of '0's

      do
        {
          s += 1 ;
          if (s == N)
            return 0 ;          // String is all '0's !!
        }
      while (str[s] == '0') ;

      s0 = s ;                  // rotate initial run of '0's
    }
  else
    {
      // First digit is '1', but if last digit is also '1', need to rotate.

      if (str[N-1] == '1')
        {
          // Step past the leading run of '1's and set length s1.
          // This run will be appended to the last run of '1's in the string

          do
            {
              s += 1 ;
              if (s == N)
                return 0 ;      // String is all '1's !!
            }
          while (str[s] == '1') ;

          s1 = s ;              // rotate initial run of '1's

          // Step past the (now) leading run of '0's and set length s0.
          // This run will be appended to the last run of '1's in the string
          //
          // NB: we know there is at least one '0' and at least one '1' before
          //     the end of the string

          do { s += 1 ; } while (str[s] == '0') ;
          s0 = s - s1 ;
        } ;
    } ;

  // Scan the string to construct the vector of pairs and the list of potential
  // starts.

  nmx = (((N / 2) + 64) / 64) * 64 ;
  mem = malloc(nmx * (sizeof(pair_t) + sizeof(uint) + sizeof(uint))) ;

  pv  = (pair_t*)mem ;
  spv = (uint*)(pv  + nmx) ;
  psi = (uint*)(spv + nmx) ;

  pn  = 0 ;
  bp  = 0 ;             // no pair is 0 !
  bpi = 0 ;
  bsc = 0 ;             // no best yet

  do
    {
      uint x1, x0 ;
      pair_t xp ;

      psi[pn] = s ;
      x1 = x0 = 0 ;
      do
        {
          x1 += 1 ;
          s  += 1 ;

          ch = (s < N) ? str[s] : '\0' ;
        }
      while (ch == '1') ;

      if (ch == '\0')
        {
          x1 += s1 ;
          x0  = s0 ;
        }
      else
        {
          do
            {
              x0 += 1 ;
              s  += 1 ;

              ch = (s < N) ? str[s] : '\0' ;
            }
          while (str[s] == '0') ;

          if (ch == '\0')
            x0 += s0 ;
        } ;

      // Register pair (x1,x0)

     reg:
      pv[pn] = xp = ((uint64_t)x1 << 32) - x0 ;

if (debug && (N == 264))
  printf("si=%u, sn=%u, pn=%u, xp=%lx bp=%lx\n", psi[sn], sn, pn, xp, bp) ;

      if      (xp > bp)
        {
          // New best start.

          bpi = pn ;
          bsc = 0 ;
          bp  = xp ;
        }
      else
        bsc += (xp == bp) ;

      pn += 1 ;
    }
  while (ch != '\0') ;

  // If there are 2 or more best starts, need to find them all, but discard
  // second and subsequent contiguous ones.

  spv[0] = bpi ;
  sn     = 1 ;

  if (bsc != 0)
    {
      uint  pi ;
      bool  rp ;

      pi = bpi ;
      rp = true ;

      do
        {
          pi += 1 ;

          if (pv[pi] != bp)
            rp = false ;
          else
            {
              bsc -= 1 ;
              if (!rp)
                {
                  spv[sn++] = pi ;
                  rp = true ;
                } ;
            } ;
        }
      while (bsc != 0) ;
    } ;

  // We have:  pn pairs in pv[]
  //           sn start positions in sv[]

  for (uint i = 1 ; sn > 1 ; ++i)
    {
      uint sc ;
      uint pi ;
      pair_t bp ;

if (debug && (N == 264))
  {
    printf("i=%u, sn=%u, pv:", i, sn) ;

    for (uint s = 0 ; s < sn ; ++s)
      printf(" %u", psi[spv[s]]) ;

    printf("\n") ;
  } ;

      pi = spv[0] + i ;                 // index of first s+i pair
      if (pi >= pn) { pi -= pn ; } ;

      bp = pv[pi] ;                     // best value, so far.
      sc = 1 ;                          // new count of best starts

      for (uint sj = 1 ; sj < sn ; ++sj)
        {
          // Consider the ith pair ahead of sj -- compare with best so far.

          uint  pb, pj ;
          pair_t xp ;

          pb = spv[sj] ;
          pj = pb + i ;                 // index of next s+i pair
          if (pj >= pn) { pj -= pn ; } ;

          xp = pv[pj] ;

          if    (xp == bp)
            {
              // sj is equal to the best so far
              //
              // So we keep both, unless we have the 'A==zA==z' case,
              // where 'z == xp == sp', the current 'ith' position.

              uint pa ;

              pa = pi + 1 ;
              if (pa == pn) { pa = 0 ; } ;  // position after first 'z'

              // If this is not an A==zA==z case, keep sj
              // Otherwise, drop sj (by not putting it back into the list),
              // but update pi so can spot A==zA==zA===z etc. cases.

              if (pa != pb)
                spv[sc++] = spv[sj] ;       // keep sj
              else
                pi = pj ;                   // for further repeats
            }
          else if (xp < bp)
            {
              // sj is less than best -- do not put it back into the list
            }
          else
            {
              // sj is better than best -- discard everything so far, and
              //                           set new best.

              sc = 1 ;              // back to one start
              spv[0] = spv[sj] ;    // new best
              pi = pj ;             // new index of ith pair
              bp = xp ;             // new best pair
            } ;
        } ;

      sn = sc ;
    } ;

  s = psi[spv[0]] ;

  free(mem) ;

  return s ;
}
```

I have tested this against the brute force method given elsewhere, and as far as I can see this is (now, on 10-Apr-2020) working code.

When I timed this on my machine, for 100,000 random strings of 400,000..500,000 characters (at random) I got:

```
   Brute Force:  281.8 secs CPU
     My method:  130.3 secs CPU
```

and that's excluding the 8.3 secs to construct the random string and run an empty test.  (That may sound a lot, but for 100,000 strings of 450,000 characters, on average, that's a touch less than 1 CPU cycle per character.)

So for random strings, my complicated method is a little over twice as fast as brute-force.  But it uses ~N*16 bytes of memory, where the brute-force method uses N*2 bytes.  Given the effort involved, the result is not hugely gratifying.

However, I also tried two pathological cases, (1) repeated "10" and (2) repeated "10100010" and for just 1000 (not 100000) strings of 400,000..500,000 characters (at random) I got:

```
   Brute Force: (1) 1730.9   (2) 319.0 secs CPU
     My method:        0.7         0.7 secs CPU
```

That **O***(n^2)* will kill you every time !

Comment: FWIW, I added some code to this answer, and have just revised it.  I did some timings, and for random strings this a little over twice as fast as @chqrlie-for-yellow-blockquotes brute-force method -- which is OK, but not earth shattering.  For pathological cases (eg repeated "10") my method *much* faster -- almost worth the effort !

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I was thinking that in case of repeated `10` and other kinds of repetition, maybe we can exploit the pattern emerging I guess to make the brute-force method much faster.

Comment: Could you tell me how you benchmark your solution with another one, like in general how you benchmark the code in order to find out which is faster?

Comment: In this case I just used `clock()` from `<time.h>`.  I ran (as noted above) many test cases, so that (1) the running time is large compared to the resolution of the clock (which on my machine is 1 micro-second per tick, and (2) so that any noise in the timing is small compared to the time measured.  I also arranged the timing loop so that the function being tested could be skipped, so that I could time everything *other than* the function.  Note, one of the things you have to watch out for is the compiler optimising away loops where the result of the loop body is not used !

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int convt(int N,string S)
{
    int sum=0;
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        int num=S[i];
        sum += pow(2,N-1-i)*(num-48);
    }
    return sum;

}

string rot(int N, string S)
{
    int temp;
    temp = S[0];
    for( int i=0; i<N;i++)
        S[i]=S[i+1];
    S[N-1]=temp;
    return S;
}

int main() {
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        int N,K;
        cin>>N;
        cin>>K;
        char S[N];
        for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
            cin>>S[i];
        string SS= S;
        int mx_val=INT_MIN;
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
        {

         string S1=rot(N,SS);
         SS= S1;
         int k_val=convt(N,SS);
         if (k_val>mx_val)
            mx_val=k_val;

        }
        int ki=0;
        int j=0;
        string S2=S;
        while(ki!=K)
        {
          S2=rot(N,S2);

          if (convt(N,S2)==mx_val)
              ki++;

          j++;

        }
        cout<<j<<endl;


    }



}
```